# Compute the distance from a point to polygon given the point and direction

Tags: python, geometry, intersection, shapely, numpy

I want to compute the distance from a point to a polygon given the point and direction. Currently I am using shapely and defining a "somewhat" infinite line string. This is not ideal as I can't actually create an infinite line string due to there being a maximum limit on the floating point value. Here I just use 10e10 to represent a really long line. Is there a better way to do this?

```
        def distance_between_point_and_polygon(point, polygon, direction)
            """
            Args:
                point: (1x2) numpy array/torch tensor
                polygon: (Nx2) numpy array/torch tensor
                direction: (1x2) numpy array/torch tensor
            """
            polygon_shapely_linestring = LineString(polygon)

            # Create infinite line string based on point and direction.
            inf_line_string = LineString([point, point + direction * 10e10])
            
            # Compute the intersecting points between the infinite line and the polygon
            intersecting_points = polygon_shapely_linestring.intersection(inf_line_string)
            
            # If there are multiple intersections, take the first one as that is the first point of intersection
            # between the ray and the polygon and this is the point needed to compute the distance to the polygon
            if isinstance(intersecting_points, Point):
                intersecting_point = intersecting_points
            elif isinstance(intersecting_points, MultiPoint):
                intersecting_point = intersecting_points[0]
            else:
                # raise some error as there is no intersection

            # Compute the distance from the point to the first intersection with the polygon
            distance = LineString([point, intersecting_point]).length

            return distance
```

For example this is what I expect:

```
    polygon = torch.tensor([[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]], dtype=torch.float64)

    points = torch.tensor([[0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0], [-4.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5]], dtype=torch.float64)
    directions = torch.tensor([[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.5, 0.5]], dtype=torch.float64)

    print(distance_between_point_and_polygon(point, polygon, direction))
    >>> torch.tensor([0.0, 1.4142135382, torch.nan, 0.7071067811], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually am using the max. span of the polygon to define the length of the line that you are intersecting the polygon with. this must work all the times. But i think 1e10 will do the same trick.