# How to determine the order of shapely's intersection function between two LineStrings

Tags: python, geometry, intersection, shapely, numpy

I want to find all the `Point` intersections between two shapely `LineString`s. It is possible that there are multiple intersections and hence the output can be a `MultiPoint`. How do I know that the output will always be ordered?

Currently it seems to be the case as seen in the example below, but how can I be sure?

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon
linestring1 = LineString([[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1]])
linestring2 = LineString([[0.5,0], [0.5,1]])
print(linestring1.intersection(linestring2))

>>> MULTIPOINT (0.5 0, 0.5 1)
```

Comment: not only can there be multiple intersection points, there can be multiple geometries, since the intersection may contain LineStrings in addition to points.

Comment: Assuming by "ordered" you mean the intersection points are ordered along one of the input LineStrings, the ordering may be different between the two input LineStrings. For example, consider the intersection of a spiral with a line.

Comment: Ah yeah, that is a good point about the multiple geometries. My main goal is to find the distance to the first point of intersection from linestring1 to linestring2.

Comment: Also a great point about the intersection between two linestrings. I was wondering if the order of `linestring1.intersection(linestring2)` would determine what the output order is.

Comment: Does this follow on from your [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424960/compute-the-distance-from-a-point-to-polygon-given-the-point-and-direction)? If so, you can convert your Multipoint to Points and calculate the distance between each intersection point and the original point from which you cast your ray. The smallest distance will be the first intersection.

Comment: Yep it does, and I ended up computing for the smallest distance. It seems the outputs are unordered. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you ask for the *difference* instead of the intersection, then the result seems to be ordered. I haven't found anything in the documentation that guarantees that though.

```
>>> l1 = LineString([(0, 0), (1000, 0)])
>>> l2 = Point(0, 0).buffer(10).exterior
>>> l3 = Point(15, 0).buffer(2).exterior
>>> difference = l1.difference(GeometryCollection([l2, l3]))
>>> difference.wkt
'MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 10 0), (10 0, 13 0), (13 0, 17 0), (17 0, 1000 0))'
```

If I cast a ray out to the right from the origin, where does it first intersect with a circle of radius 10 centered at the origin and a circle of radius 2 centered at `(15, 0)`?  We can see that using `difference()` has split `l1` into pieces where it intersected `l2` and `l3`, and those pieces are returned in order.

You can grab the endpoint of the first LineString in the result, and that's the first intersection point.  So far I haven't seen this ordering vary.